# <Set> to <List> causes ConcurrentExecutionException

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have a set of threads updating a `SynchronizedSet` which I need to send converted to a `SynchronizedList` later. The code is below.

```
public class TestMapper {

    private static Set<String> outputSet;
    private static List<String> outputList;

    public TestMapper() throws IOException {
        outputSet = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<String>());
    }

    protected  static void copyFile(String docPath) throws IOException {
        outputSet.add(docPath);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected static void Mapper(int numThreads) throws Exception {
        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
        final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Future<?>> futures = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Future<?>>();
        final JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        try {
            Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get("/test"), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFile(final Path tFile, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                    futures.add((Future<String>) executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            JsonObject jsonObject = null;
                            FileReader reader = null;
                            try {
                                reader = new FileReader(tFile.toFile());
                                jsonObject = (JsonObject) parser.parse(reader); 
                                copyFile(jsonObject.get("instances").get(0));
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            } finally {
                                try {
                                    if (reader != null)
                                        reader.close();
                                } 
                            }                           
                        }
                    }));
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }
            });
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } 
        finally {
            Future<?> future;
            while ((future = futures.poll()) != null) {
                try {
                    future.get();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    for (Future<?> f : futures)
                        f.cancel(true);
                    if (executorService != null)
                        executorService.shutdown();
                    throw new Exception(e);
                }
            }
            if (executorService != null)
                executorService.shutdown();
        }
    }

    protected static void another(List<String> outputList1) throws Exception {
         AnotherClass.read(outputList1);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int numThreads = 4;
        TestMapper dam = new TestMapper();
        dam.Mapper(numThreads);
        outputList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>(outputSet));
        dam.another(outputList);
    }
}
```

But the following exception is thrown @line `dam.another(outputList);`
Why does this occur? This issue does not occur if the directory `/test` has 5 files, but happens when there is 5000 files

```
 [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 [java]     at com.test.AnotherClass.read(AnotherClass.java:105)
 [java]     at com.test.TestMapper.another(TestMapper.java:71)
 [java]     at com.test.TestMapper.main(TestMapper.java:80)
 [java] Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 [java]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:133)
 [java]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:199)
 [java]     ... 2 more
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 [java]     at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:564)
 [java]     at java.util.LinkedList.get(LinkedList.java:485)
```

Comment: The underlying exception is an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Are you sure that `outputList` contains elements?

Comment: Always read the stacktrace from bottom to up :)

Comment: Can you share source code of AnotherClass.read(outputList.. )

Comment: @ThomasOwens: Yes the elements are added in outputSet so if I'm right outputList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>(outputSet)); sets the elements from the outputSet. Since threads access the outputSet is that causing some concurrentExecutionException error? And this happens only for large number of files not for 10 or 20 files in the test directory..

Comment: Try adding a sysout to :`copyFile(jsonObject.get("instances").get(0));System.out.println(jsonObject.get("instances").get(0));`
Check if that prints something.

Comment: @YassinHajaj: Yes it does print the docPath